SupplyParameterFromQuery not working in Blazor app
In my .NET 8 Blazor Server App, I am using [SupplyParameterFromQuery] to retrieve query string parameters as recommended by Microsoft here.
Home.razor
@page "/home"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<p>
    <label>
         <input @bind="zipcode" />
    </label>
</p>


@code{
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public int? zipcode { get; set; }
}

To test, I navigate to my app with this URL: https://localhost:1234/home?zipcode=90210
But zipcode is NULL
My guess is that [SupplyParameterFromQuery] is obsolete or this is a bug.  Maybe there is another way I'm supposed to get query parameters?

I pasted your code "as is" and it worked in both a wasm and a server app (.net 8.0). You may need more details to re-create the error your seeing.

[Polite] "My guess is that [SupplyParameterFromQuery] is obsolete or this is a bug. "  Neither, it's your code.  There's something you're not showing that is causing the problem.  Create a new project, add your code and it will work.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I hope you're right, although my project is a brand new hello world app.

@KidBilly Is the issue checked and solved? Since I got the same correct behavior as other members. If not please describe more clearly how you started the new app , and what is the console of your browser.

As it's a demo project, can you temporarily publish it to Github?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis  I created a github repo here: https://github.com/bkindig/InquiryForms/
Thanks again for helping me.

It works.  See my answer.

Using your GitHub repo I've modified your Home to show the zipcode property.
@page "/homeowner"
@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<input class="form-control" @bind="zipcode" />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public int? zipcode { get; set; }

    public string teststr = "abc";
}

The result is as I would expect:


Using your changes, it does work.  I think I wasn't understanding, but it was working all along.  Anyway, thank you for your time! :)
